# Интеграция PHP приложения с JIRA

Tags: php, интеграция, jira

Добрый день, появилась задача интегрировать веб приложение с `JIRA`. Так как с `JIRA` ни разу не работал - не знаю в какую сторону копать. В документации `JIRA` написано, что есть `REST API`, но библиотеку найти не могу. Может быть, для работы с их `API` нужно что-то ещё, например, оплатить аккаунт? Поделитесь кто сталкивался. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Документация:
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Библиотеки для работы с JIRA API на php (неофициальные):

1. https://github.com/chobie/jira-api-restclient
2. https://github.com/cpliakas/jira-client
3. https://github.com/lesstif/php-jira-rest-client

Comment: Из документации я понял, что сначала нужно добавить ссылку на своё приложение и настроить OAuth аутентификацию, тут у меня возникли вопросы:
1. Моё приложение находится на localhost, можно ли мне привязать его?(подозреваю что нет, по крайней буде только односторонняя связь)
2. Какой тип приложения нужно выбирать из списка? (crowd, confluence, Atlassian connect, базовое приложение...etc)
3. Где взять такие данные как Ключ покупателя, Shared secret (у меня 10 дневный триал)? Обязательно ли в моём случае проплачивать аккаунт?
4. При настройке OAuth нужно ввести "Открытый ключ", где взять его?